# Returning results in their order from multiple api queries

Tags: javascript

I want to make multiple API calls from an array of values. I would like to resolve the first call, then the second, third, and so on in the order in which the API request receives the data. everything I've tried gets me to the point of logging the final data in the console or resolving the data but not necessarily returning the array of data in the format with which the requests were made. Below is one of the solutions I was recently playing with. It definitely does not work (and there are a lot of issues with it) but I do see the unresolved data in the console. The `console.logs` just show the points where some sort of accurate data is returned as an unresolved promise

Function

```
const sendTrackingData =  (storeKey, deliveries) => {
    const trackingUrl = deliveries.map(async (delivery) => {
        const urlData = []

        delivery.parcels.map(async (parcel) => {
            const {trackingData} = parcel;
            const carrier = trackingData.carrier.toLowerCase();
            const trackingCode = trackingData.trackingId;
            urlData.push(await getTrackingUrl(storeKey, carrier, trackingCode))
        })
        console.log(urlData)
        return urlData
    })
    return Promise.all(trackingUrl)
};
```

It is called here for now in a `use effect`

```
    const test = await sendTrackingData(storeKey, deliveries)
    console.log(test,'the test url data =========>')
```

API call

```
export const getTrackingUrl =  (storeKey, carrier, trackingCode) => {
    return axios.post(`random-url-address/returnedData`, {
        storeKey,
        carrier,
        trackingCode,
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `Promise.all` *on the main asynchronous requests* - the `getTrackingUrl` - for the order to be preserved:

```
const sendTrackingData = (storeKey, deliveries) => (
    Promise.all(deliveries.map((delivery) => (
        Promise.all(delivery.parcels.map((parcel) => {
            const { trackingData } = parcel;
            const carrier = trackingData.carrier.toLowerCase();
            const trackingCode = trackingData.trackingId;
            return getTrackingUrl(storeKey, carrier, trackingCode);
        }))
    )))
);
```

When you want to preserve order, `.push` after an asynchronous request is almost never the right approach.

Comment: I didn't like `.push` ugly and can't do the job. You were right about calling Prmise.all on the asynchronous requests, thanks for taking the time

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```js
delivery.parcels.map(async (parcel , index) => {
            const {trackingData} = parcel;
            const carrier = trackingData.carrier.toLowerCase();
            const trackingCode = trackingData.trackingId;
            
            urlData.splice(index, 0, await getTrackingUrl(storeKey, carrier, trackingCode));
        })
        console.log(urlData)
        return urlData
```

Comment: My code returns a promise so ultimately this solution wouldn't work, thanks for the attempt though :)